# Python Selenium Proxy in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I have been searching loads of forums for using a proxy in python with the selenium library to prevent "max number" timeout with web scraping through selenium.

I found the script below in many forums, but it just doesn't seem to work for me whatsoever... Could anyone please help me and give me some advice on how to implement proxy in chrome through python with selenium.

Thanks a lot!

SCRIPT:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = directory....
PROXY = "177.202.59.58:8080"
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Comment: Update the question with _`max number`_ timeout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. That proxy is just not available/not working anymore.
Try to find another proxy that a better uptime. Keep it mind that public proxies have a noticeable latency so the page will load pretty slow.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, many thanks for your help!